# JEditorPane inside a JScrollPane not showing scroll bar

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, jscrollbar

I am trying to embed a webpage in a JScrollPane which is inside a JEditorPane which is a rectangle inside a JFrame, Like in HTML how you have a webpage and then can have a small rectangle somewhere on the webpage that has an iframe of another webpage. The reason I have a rectangle defined using setBounds is because the rectangle is smaller than the actual window, because there are other elements in the window.

```
        JEditorPane web = new JEditorPane();
    web.setEditable(false);  

    try {
      web.setPage("http://www.example.com");
    }catch (IOException e) {
      web.setContentType("text/html");
      web.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
    } 
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(web);     
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() { 
               scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
           }
        });
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    rweb = new Rectangle(20, 20, 1150, 600);
    web.setBounds(rweb);
    window.add(web);
```

Comment: No sentence here ends with a question mark.

Comment: @Ross Your seriously commenting about that? Very constructive. Just edit the question. One "?" is missing at the end, and a "Why is " at the beginning. Example: "Why is a JEditorPane inside a JScrollPane not vertically scrolling?"

Comment: I agree with Ross, what is the problem exactly? The scroll bars dont show up? They do but scrolling doesnt function? The entire frame is empty? What is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I am @maythesource.com  This is a "question and answer" site, not a "make a statement and have people guess your intention" site.  "not vertically scrolling" is a vague statement.  It could mean the bar is there but not scrolling, that there is no bar, that the bar moves but the box doesn't scroll, that there is nothing there...

Comment: OK, so the correct comment would be "Please explain in more detail what the actual problem is". Not commenting vaguely about question marks. Also not vertically scrolling can mean one of two things: either the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear, or it does but it doesn't work (frozen or disabled). Only way to figure that out is to try the code, or have a ton of experience in relation to GUI.

Comment: There was no vagueness in my statement, neither was it wrong so you cannot correct it thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `setBounds()`? This makes your `JEditorPane` size absolute, i.e. non-resizable and `JScrollPane` only works if it's resizable.  Remove `setBounds()`.

Also, you are adding the `JEditorPane` to your window and not the `JScrollBar` so you're skipping the functionality of the `JScrollBar`.

[image]

So just changing your last lines fixes your problem

```
//rweb = new Rectangle(20, 20, 1150, 600);
//web.setBounds(rweb);
window.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: I dont think this is the case Ross, can you post some code? In my testing here I changed the setBounds call to the parent frame, still no scroll bar.

Comment: try removing the `setBounds()` line all together

Comment: Still no scroll bars :/

Comment: added an image, only difference is the removal of `setBounds` you cna see the window, with scroll bar

Comment: My bad...I noticed I changed one more thing, I did it without thinking

Comment: Yeah a combination of things here. Adding via the getContentPane() method where the scrollPane is added, and in addition adding the wrong component at the end. It appears that the JScrollPane was added to the frame and just very very small so not visible, and the editor pane was being rendered next to the invisible scrollpane.

Answer (score 3):

I simplified your code. The following works.

You had many extra statements that complicated things such as adding `web` two times (once to Scroll and once to JFrame).

Another example is `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);` . The scrollbar by default starts at zero.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class webPane extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         webPane e = new  webPane();
         e.setVisible(true);         
    }


    public webPane() {

        JEditorPane web = new JEditorPane();
        web.setEditable(false);

        try {
            web.setPage("http://www.cnn.com");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            web.setContentType("text/html");
            web.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
        }

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(web);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        this.setBounds( 0, 0, 200, 200);

    }

}
```

Comment: No explanation of what you did to fix it or what was wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Comment: I do explain what one of the problems was.

Comment: Now you do.  When I down-voted, you didn't.  It was a code only answer.